# Conversion from VBA to JS - wrong output

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, vba

I got the following code in VBA from my customer:

```vb
Sub calculate()
    Range("B1") = 0
    Range("B2") = 0
    Range("B3") = 0
    Range("B4") = 0
    Range("B5") = 0
    Range("B6") = 0
    Range("B7") = 0

    Dim Duration
    Dim SaldoPrimo
    Dim SaldoUltimo

    Duration = 0
    SaldoPrimo = 0
    SaldoUltimo = 0
    MonthInterestAmount = 0
    RunningAdm = 0
    RunningInterest = 0
    ExtraOrdinaryInstallment = 0


    LoanAmount = Range("F3")
    FixedPrice = Range("F4")
    MonthInterest = Range("F5")
    OpeningFee = Range("F6")
    MonthFee = Range("F7")
    SaldoPrimo = LoanAmount + OpeningFee

    Do
        Duration = Duration + 1
        MonthInterestAmount = SaldoPrimo * MonthInterest
        SaldoUltimo = SaldoPrimo + MonthFee + MonthInterestAmount - FixedPrice
        
        RunningAdm = RunningAdm + MonthFee
        RunningInterest = RunningInterest + MonthInterestAmount
        
        SaldoPrimo = SaldoUltimo
                
        If Duration > 400 Then Exit Sub
        
        SaldoTest = SaldoUltimo + (SaldoPrimo * MonthInterest) + MonthFee

    Loop Until SaldoTest < FixedPrice
    
    
    If SaldoUltimo > 0 Then
       
       MonthInterestAmount = SaldoPrimo * MonthInterest
       Duration = Duration + 1
       RunningAdm = RunningAdm + MonthFee
       RunningInterest = RunningInterest + MonthInterestAmount
       ExtraOrdinaryInstallment = MonthInterestAmount + MonthFee + SaldoUltimo
       Range("B11") = MonthInterestAmount + MonthFee + SaldoUltimo
    End If
    
    
    SaldoPrimo = 0
    SaldoUltimo = 0
        
        
    TotalCost = RunningAdm + RunningInterest + OpeningFee
    Totalpay = LoanAmount + TotalCost

    Range("B1") = Duration
    Range("B2") = SaldoPrimo
    Range("B3") = SaldoUltimo
    Range("B4") = RunningAdm
    Range("B5") = RunningInterest
    Range("B6") = TotalCost
    Range("B7") = Totalpay
    Range("B8") = FixedPrice
    Range("B9") = ExtraOrdinaryInstallment  
End Sub
```

Values: F3: 250000, F4: 3499, F5: 0.41, F6: 3499, F7: 99

I "translated" into JavaScript (and changed input/output from Excel cells to text-inputs (for input) divs with ids (for output)) into this:

```js
function calculate()
{
    let Duration=0;
    let SaldoPrimo=0;
    let SaldoUltimo=0;
    let MonthInterestAmount = 0;
    let RunningAdm = 0;
    let RunningInterest = 0;
    let ExtraOrdinaryInstallment = 0;

    LoanAmount=parseFloat($('#input_loan_amount').val());
    FixedPrice=parseFloat($('#input_installment').val());
    MonthInterest=parseFloat($('#input_monthly_interest').val());
    OpeningFee=parseFloat($('#input_initial_fee').val());
    MonthFee=parseFloat($('#input_monthly_fee').val());
    SaldoPrimo=LoanAmount+OpeningFee;
    do
     {
         Duration++;
         MonthInterestAmout=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
         SaldoUltimo=SaldoPrimo+MonthFee+MonthInterest-FixedPrice;
         RunningAdm=RunningAdm+MonthFee;
         RunningInterest=RunningInterest+MonthInterestAmount;
         SaldoPrimo=SaldoUltimo;
         if (Duration>400)
         {
             break;
         }
         SaldoTest=SaldoUltimo+(SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest)+MonthFee;
    }
    while (SaldoTest < FixedPrice);

    if (SaldoUltimo>0)
     {
         MonthInterestAmount=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
         Duration++;
         RunningAdm=RunningAdm+MonthFee;
         RunningInterest=RunningInterest+MonthInterestAmount;
         ExtraOrdinaryInstallment=MonthInterestAmount+MonthFee+SaldoUltimo;
         $('#result').html((MonthInterestAmount+MonthFee+SaldoUltimo));
     }
    SaldoPrimo=0;
    SaldoUltimo=0;
    let TotalCost=RunningAdm+RunningInterest+OpeningFee;
    let Totalpay=LoanAmount+TotalCost;
    $('#Duration').html(Duration);
    $('#SaldoPrimo').html(SaldoPrimo);
    $('#SaldoUltimo').html(SaldoUltimo);
    $('#RunningAdm').html(RunningAdm);
    $('#RunningInterest').html(RunningInterest);
    $('#TotalCost').html(TotalCost);
    $('#Totalpay').html(Totalpay);
    $('#FixedPrice').html(FixedPrice);
    $('#ExtraOrdinaryInstallment').html(ExtraOrdinaryInstallment);
}
```

Values: $('#input_loan_amount').val: 250000, $('#input_installment').val: 3499, $('#input_monthly_interest').val: 0.41, $('#input_initial_fee').val: 3499, $('#input_monthly_fee').val: 99

Despite the same input from Excel and the text-inputs, the results are different.
E.g. the Duration in Excel/VBA is 90, while it is 2 in JavaScript.
Could it be that do/while in JS does not do the same as do/loop until in VBA?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can improve the question by editing your question to include the sample values you used for both sets of code i.e. what values are in the range `F3-F7` in the spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 2):

A few changes should allow the JavaScript code to produce the same output as the Excel sheet.

The major change is converting the VB *loop until* to a JavaScript *while ()* statement.

The others are just minor errors/typos.

Also added a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vxr04knq/1/ (updated)

###### Changes

###### a.

```
while (SaldoTest < FixedPrice);
```

to

```
while (!(SaldoTest < FixedPrice));
```

(Since the VB code loops *until*, which is the opposite of while).
You could also change to while (FixedPrice <= SaldoTest).

###### b.

```
MonthInterestAmout=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
```

to

```
MonthInterestAmount=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
```

(Just a typo probably)

###### c.

```
SaldoUltimo=SaldoPrimo+MonthFee+MonthInterest-FixedPrice;
```

to

```
SaldoUltimo=SaldoPrimo+MonthFee+MonthInterestAmount-FixedPrice;
```

Since we want the MonthInterestAmount to be added, not the MonthInterest (rate).

**Update:** I've also updated to multiply the MonthInterest input by (1/100) to reflect the user inputting as a percentage.

Complete JavaScript / HTML code:

```js
function calculate()
{
    let Duration=0;
    let SaldoPrimo=0;
    let SaldoUltimo=0;
    let MonthInterestAmount = 0;
    let RunningAdm = 0;
    let RunningInterest = 0;
    let ExtraOrdinaryInstallment = 0;

    LoanAmount=parseFloat($('#input_loan_amount').val());
    FixedPrice=parseFloat($('#input_installment').val());
    // Divide interest rate by 100 since user will enter a percentage. 
    MonthInterest=(1/100)*parseFloat($('#input_monthly_interest').val());
    OpeningFee=parseFloat($('#input_initial_fee').val());
    MonthFee=parseFloat($('#input_monthly_fee').val());
    SaldoPrimo=LoanAmount+OpeningFee;
    do
     {
         Duration++;
         MonthInterestAmount=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
         SaldoUltimo=SaldoPrimo+MonthFee+MonthInterestAmount-FixedPrice;

         RunningAdm=RunningAdm+MonthFee;
         RunningInterest=RunningInterest+MonthInterestAmount;
         SaldoPrimo=SaldoUltimo;
         if (Duration>400)
         {
             break;
         }
         SaldoTest=SaldoUltimo+(SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest)+MonthFee;
    }
    while (!(SaldoTest < FixedPrice)); // VB: Loop Until SaldoTest < FixedPrice

    if (SaldoUltimo>0)
     {
         MonthInterestAmount=SaldoPrimo*MonthInterest;
         Duration++;
         RunningAdm=RunningAdm+MonthFee;
         RunningInterest=RunningInterest+MonthInterestAmount;
         ExtraOrdinaryInstallment=MonthInterestAmount+MonthFee+SaldoUltimo;
         $('#result').html((MonthInterestAmount+MonthFee+SaldoUltimo));
     }
    SaldoPrimo=0;
    SaldoUltimo=0;
    let TotalCost=RunningAdm+RunningInterest+OpeningFee;
    let Totalpay=LoanAmount+TotalCost;
    $('#Duration').html(Duration);
    $('#SaldoPrimo').html(SaldoPrimo);
    $('#SaldoUltimo').html(SaldoUltimo);
    $('#RunningAdm').html(RunningAdm);
    $('#RunningInterest').html(RunningInterest);
    $('#TotalCost').html(TotalCost);
    $('#Totalpay').html(Totalpay);
    $('#FixedPrice').html(FixedPrice);
    $('#ExtraOrdinaryInstallment').html(ExtraOrdinaryInstallment);
}

calculate()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<label for="input_loan_amount">Loan amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_loan_amount" name="input_loan_amount" value="250000">
<br>
 
<label for="input_loan_amount">Fixed price:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_installment" name="input_installment" value="3499">
<br>
 
<label for="input_loan_amount">Monthly interest:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_monthly_interest" name="input_monthly_interest" value="0.41">
<br>
 
<label for="input_loan_amount">Initial fee:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_initial_fee" name="input_initial_fee" value="3499">
<br>
 
<label for="input_monthly_fee">Monthly fee:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_monthly_fee" name="input_monthly_fee" value="99">
<br>
<br>
 
 
<b>Duration: </b><i id="Duration"></i><br>
<b>Saldo Primo: </b><i id="SaldoPrimo"></i><br>
<b>Saldo Ultimo: </b><i id="SaldoUltimo"></i><br>
<b>RunningAdm: </b><i id="RunningAdm"></i><br>
<b>RunningInterest: </b><i id="RunningInterest"></i><br>
<b>TotalCost: </b><i id="TotalCost"></i><br>
<b>Totalpay: </b><i id="Totalpay"></i><br>
<b>FixedPrice: </b><i id="FixedPrice"></i><br>
<b>ExtraOrdinaryInstallment: </b><i id="ExtraOrdinaryInstallment"></i><br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry. This is better, but it is not doing what I meant it to do:
Now, the loop is running from 1 to 401 (or actually from 0 to 400), but is not calculating anything. Then it breaks due to if(Duration>400), while it actually should break at 90, since the debt comes below the "fixed price".

Comment: Can you check in the snippet above, or the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0g98kbt4/2/, I'm getting a Duration of 90, the same as the Excel Sheet?

Comment: That is strange! It does give a Duration of 90 in the JSFiddle.
Somehow I might be making a mistake. Perhaps somewhere with the monthly interest, which should be 0.0041 (as in your version) where a user normally enters 0.41 (as in percent). I will check out where I am going wrong this time, but I am sure your script is doing the correct thing.

Albert

Comment: You might simply need to divide your monthly interest input by 100.0, since your form probably takes the percentage amount (0.41%) rather than 0.0041. I've updated the snippet to do this.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxr04knq/1/ this takes an interest rate in %, so it should match up with your form.

Comment: Brilliant, Terry! Thank you so much! I might have made a mistake somehow while copying your code, because now it's working! And thanks for the updated Fiddle.

Albert

Comment: Great, glad to be of help. It was an interesting problem!

Comment: It was! Besides my two typos, I was on the right way, but couldn't see the forest before the trees!
In addition to this, I have another question, which I will post separately: to do the same calculation without recursive counting, but with Math.log.

Comment: If you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901205/javascript-math-log-in-stead-of-resursive-method-flaw-in-my-formula

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239045/discussion-between-albert-van-harten-and-terry-lennox).